# Facebook Login Using React Js

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, typescript, express, mern

I want to implement Facebook login in my application, I am using MERN, Only client side facebook button is showing, but token is getting saved in mongodb

Comment: Use can use `passportjs`'s Facebook strategy. http://www.passportjs.org/docs/facebook/

Comment: Thats the problem i am facing, On hitting the URL the passport js service is nit getting triggered